# What is the difference between straight calling a function and assigning it to a variable?

Tags: python, computer-science

I know this is a super basic question, but I need to know if I understand.

If I have this function:

```
def fn():
    # connections to a db and builts tables and runs things externally
    return "all the tables that were built"
```

if I write:

```
x = fn()
```

do all those external operations still happen? like the tables being built and all that?

or do I run this:

```
fn()
```

to have them built?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, the function runs regardless of whether or not you use its results. In Python, there's no way for a function to know what you're planning to do with its result (some languages, like Perl, allow functions to detect whether or not a function result is used, but Python is not one of them).

Comment: @SilvioMayolo thank you just had to be sure. So x = fn(), all those tables and logic will still be carried out even though it's being assigned to a variable?

Comment: Yes, and it's not hard to test. put a `print` statement inside the function. And the function `fn` isn't assigned to a variable. The `return`ed value is.

Comment: @Axe319 Not necessarily, see my example.

Comment: @KellyBundy True, but have you ever actually seen code like that in production or even something that isn't merely a proof of concept? IMO, this isn't within the spirit of the question and will only serve to confuse someone that is still learning the basics of the python execution model.

Comment: @Axe319 I don't think I have, but I haven't seen much (or any?) code like what they're talking about in general. And their *"all those tables and logic will still be carried out even though it's being assigned to a variable?"* actually made me wonder whether they had in mind something like what I showed, i.e., that keeping it alive in the variable prevents some finalization.

Comment: @KellyBundy Originally, I think I misinterpreted it as a function object vs. function call question from the comment. Specifically, `"So x = fn(), all those tables and logic will still be carried out even though it's being assigned to a variable?"`. That doesn't make a whole lot of sense in that if you receive `"all the tables that were built"` back, it seems logical that they would have been built. But the answer was accepted, so it must have sufficed.

Comment: @Axe319 Well... I'm not saying it's realistic, but maybe "built" could be as unfinished as "written" in [this somewhat similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75258406/12671057) I just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x = fn()` might do less. Imagine one of your returned tables only commits its actions when it gets deleted:

```
def fn():
    class Table:
        def __del__(self):
            print('commit')
    return Table()

x = fn()
print('last thing')
```

Output:

```
last thing
commit
```

Since we hold on to the table, it won't get deleted right away and its actions won't be committed right away. Only at the very end of the program does that happen then, when Python shuts down and deletes everything. Or maybe not even then, see [Silvio's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75253487/what-is-the-difference-between-straight-calling-a-function-and-assigning-it-to-a/75253660?noredirect=1#comment132792906_75253660) and [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) (*"It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits"*), or if Python or your computer crashes.

Output if I remove the `x =`:

```
commit
last thing
```

Now we don't hold on to the table, so nothing references it anymore and it gets deleted right away and the commit happens right away.

Comment: Nitpick: `__del__` runs when a value is garbage collected and is not guaranteed to run if the interpreter exits while the value still exists. So while this answer makes a good point, the output shown is by no means guaranteed.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo For the first version, I mentioned that myself. For the second version, at least in CPython, it pretty much *is* guaranteed, no? Because the object gets garbage collected right after the function returns since its reference count drops to zero.

Comment: Good point. I always forget CPython is still backed by a reference counter, so you're right that it should be guaranteed in the absence of reference cycles (which is not a problem in your example)