# Is it bad practice to return function from inside with statement

Tags: python, function, with-statement

Which one of the two examples below is the best practice?

```
@classmethod
def find(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    """Perform a find query in the DB."""
    with cls.connect() as conn:
        coll = conn[cls.DB][cls.COLLECTION]
        res = coll.find(*args, **kwargs)
        out = list(res)
        return out
```

```
@classmethod
def find(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    """Perform a find query in the DB."""
    with cls.connect() as conn:
        coll = conn[cls.DB][cls.COLLECTION]
        res = coll.find(*args, **kwargs)
        out = list(res)
    return out
```

I imagine this should essentially be interchangeable, since the context manager `__exit__` method should be called anyways once the function returns, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Yes, it's fairly inconsequential. I'd be more worried about the apparently purely static class with just `@classmethod`s.

Comment: Have you done anything to check whether there are any differences between your two methods?

Comment: If the second method fails within the with-statement, then out won't be defined

Comment: In the case of the connection failing, or the query failing, you may want to handle that, by either rasing an exception or returning that state to the user in some other way.

Comment: @FRINTSO Then that "fail" would terminate the entire function anyway. There's no way for it to skip the `out = ...` statement but still execute the `return out` statement. (Greatly assuming the database context manager won't swallow exceptions…)

Comment: @deceze method shouldn't be static since it uses other defined methods and attributes from the same class - which are not visible in the example because it is not really relevant to the question

Answer (score 3):

If the context manager is designed to swallow exceptions, your `out` will be undefined after `with` exits:

```
class Test:
    def __enter__(self):
        return 1

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return True


def x():
    with Test():
        some_error
        out = 1
        return out


def y():
    with Test():
        some_error
        out = 1
    return out


print(x())  # None
print(y())  # local variable 'out' referenced before assignment
```

Therefore, it makes more sense to keep `return` within the block.

Comment: My answer comes to the opposite conclusion. I think maybe in your case, the bad practice might instead be the swallowing, or that the rest of the code doesn't handle the swallowing well. But I'm not sure. Have little experience with that.

Comment: But in that case, it would be more of a problem with the CM construction itself, than with the code that utilizes the CM. So I would rather have a variable referenced before assignment error than just having this function weirdly returning None if anything inside the with statement breaks

Answer (score 1):

The context manager's exit might affect the result, so that it matters whether you `return` before or after that exit (i.e., inside or outside the `with` block). For example a function that writes a file and returns the file size:

```
from os.path import getsize

def foo():
    with open('foo', 'w') as f:
        f.write('foo')
        return getsize('foo')

def bar():
    with open('bar', 'w') as f:
        f.write('bar')
    return getsize('bar')

print(foo(), bar())
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY6xDsIwDET3fIW3JFLVhQXxN0E4NENjyzGK4OdD2qgMCIkb7073jp@6UD6dWVqLQitQmTnoAmllEoU7akkvNOaGESKR8xcDXTX1DjFmZ7trJ7DVeggF4sg3xblKUhwN/7EF9SH5WD7SHXAN8gPQ3T@ArTEA3@MjMSwpq9v/T4PiW3sD)):

```
0 3
```

When I return inside, the file hasn't been flushed/closed yet. That's wrong.

So at least in such cases, you should return outside.

(For documentation about how a `return` inside a `with` block is handled, see the "semantically equivalent" code [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement). The `with` block is executed in a `try`, and the manager's exit is done in its `finally`.)